# Puppet: How to require an additional resource in a custom type

Tags: ruby, puppet, custom-type

I am writing a custom type for Puppet and use the following code to copy a module file specified by a puppet url to the user's home directory:

```
def generate
  if self[:source]
    uri = URI.parse(self[:source])
    path = File.join(Etc.getpwnam(self[:user])[:dir], File.basename(uri.path))
    file_opts = {}
    file_opts[:name] = File.join(Etc.getpwnam(self[:user])[:dir], File.basename(uri.path))
    file_opts[:ensure] = self[:ensure] == :absent ? :absent : :file
    file_opts[:source] = self[:source]
    file_opts[:owner] = self[:user]
    self[:source] = path

    Puppet::Type.type(:file).new(file_opts)
  end
end
```

Things are working fine so far. The resource is added to the catalog and created on the agent side. But I have a problem...

How can I specify that this additional file resource must be created before the actual type gets executed? Unfortunatley, I cannot find an example which shows how to specify a dependency on an optional resource that is defined in a `generate` method.

Comment: I don't use custom types so I apologize if this comment is a bit naive, but I was trying to look up an answer for you and this sample code doesn't seem to match how the documentation looks at all. Have you tried writing it like they describe in the documentation? Maybe there's something special about putting it in the module's lib folder that helps with this solution. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_types.html

Comment: Have you tried passing a reference as `file_opts[:before]` with value `"MyType['#{self[:title]}']` or something along those lines? Not quite sure about details of dependencies on this code level off the top of my head...